# Typescript - Typing a function with optional argument correctly

Tags: typescript

Suppose we have the following function:

```ts
function test<S, T>(obj: S, prop: keyof S, mapper?: (value: S[keyof S]) => T): S[keyof S] | T {
  return typeof mapper === 'function'
    ? mapper(obj[prop])
    : obj[prop];
}
```

If then I use it without the `mapper` argument, the type of the return value is not deduced properly:

```ts
const value = test({ a: 'stringValue' }, 'a'); // value is of type "unknown"
```

But if I provide an identity function as the third parameter, it is deduced correctly:

```ts
const value = test({ a: 'stringValue' }, 'a', x => x); // value is of type "string"
```

How should the `test` function be typed so when we don't provide the `mapper` argument, the return value's type is deduced correctly?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgMoBpEAqAfABRwBGAVgFyJ6IAOATnA7QNYoCecwd+AWwCGDBiiYB+WiQBuQgDYgUtbAG1OPPtgC6ASkQBeIoV0r13XnW2IAPoUQBvALAAoRO8RMUUEEyRQuMUthUXFDAwNEAHJQSFgEKNcPZMQJRBCxJjIqVWZWPSSU91oKSlyWBm0AblcAX1dXCAQMRDlFFENkdCgSB0QhWiiMJhgwAHMANQUlKMRa-CihKN0qxAB6Ndbpjpg0REsAsUQAInB2MDgAdzBj1w3kgD0JBpcmsBa2pQAmTtQMXv6g2Go0m21m82iS3wAA9DMZoSt1ptPjs9gdAh1jsDxrcXPcPE8gA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use [function overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) !

```
function test<S, T>(obj: S, prop: keyof S): S[keyof S];
function test<S, T>(obj: S, prop: keyof S, mapper: (value: S[keyof S]) => T): T;
function test<S, T>(obj: S, prop: keyof S, mapper?: (value: S[keyof S]) => T): S[keyof S] | T {
    return typeof mapper === 'function'
        ? mapper(obj[prop])
        : obj[prop];
}

const value = test({ a: 'stringValue' }, 'a'); // string

const value2 = test({ a: 'stringValue' }, 'a', x => x);  // string
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgMoBpEAqAfABRwBGAVgFyJ6IAOATnA7QNYoCecwdAlLWwBtTjz7YAugG4AsAChQkWAmTos9YmSpD8zVh2686+ALYBDBgxRNaJAG7mANiBRDRRiZP6IAvEUJBREI5RXBoeCRUDBx8LQoaE0YWNkQxY3oLKxsAfjtHFzc6D3E6bz8AgiCRdK9EAB9CRABvBWDgphQoECYormtjLOsmP19fRAByJQiECbb2hZzEIZttSmF9Bm95heDaBI2UmQUAXwUFCAQMRALXPzUMEmbEc1oJjCYYMABzADVnVwTRAnfATcwTfjSRAKAD0MIWAD0cud5JcwNdbigAEz3aJQJ4vN4fL5-AEoIEgybg-AADwqiBpkOh8jhiJyQA)

Comment: @DMZ - Expanding on Matthieu's answer: The issue with your original code is that without a `mapper` function, there's no way for TypeScript to infer `T`, because the only place `T` exists in the parameter list is in relation to `mapper`. So `T` is `unknown`, so the result of `test` is `unknown`. The function overload solution avoids that by defining an overload without `mapper` that returns `S[keyof S]` and an overload with `mapper` that returns `T`.

Comment: I was so close. Thanks, don't know how did I miss that.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach is to help the compiler by moving more  information to the generic variables of the function. Does this work for you? ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgLAChEGIDyARgFYA0ehiACgE5wAOiKAHqmACZqIDWKAJ5xgxclXyEAsgEMmTFPVYcU3XgAp1ANxkAbECgBcYsgG0GzALoBKRAF4AfIhlhBtgD6JwXFMBhgULjwHdWpCOHJjUkowgiZGJmMLJgkaAFs5BXoAfmNZeUU8a2NvX39A5U4eRHysxGyTcwTLRGMAJRQoEHowABVBBUwAOQQhkF1dGRJdFExaxQcnAG9YxHpO7qQMgqUG7az1CLN4q1tjI9MTpksAbjwAXzw8CAQMRB19FABGe2R0KHUS2cxgARF8AEwAZhBiHuFEQIJkIOsd1wz1eUHeegM4N+qAwgOBCIh0Nh8MRIPhbHsTiYMnoaBQAEkwAC2NYUUA))

```
function test<
    Obj,
    Prop extends keyof Obj,
    Mapper extends ((value: Obj[Prop]) => any) | undefined
>(
    obj: Obj,
    prop: Prop,
    mapper?: Mapper
): undefined extends Mapper ? Obj[Prop] : ReturnType<NonNullable<Mapper>> {
    return mapper ? mapper(obj[prop]) : obj[prop];
}

const value1 = test({ a: "123" }, "a");

const value2 = test({ a: "123" }, "a", x => parseInt(x));
```

The optional mapper makes the code harder to write, but I am pretty sure this code can be simplified further.

Comment: Interesting approach, this works as well. The "undefined extends Mapper" is kind of confusing though.

Comment: You can also write the more natural `[Mapper] extends [Function] ? ReturnType<Mapper> : Obj[Prop]`, but the non-distributive extends may be also confusing for TS newcomers.